# The difference about times and plus in a GLM?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, interaction

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between interaction and plus in a GLM function?

If we have a categorical variable with two or more levels and some continuous variables, then we should use the gaussian as the family in the glm function.  Plus, the response variable is a continous variable, and other variables including the categorical variables are explanatory variables.

But what about the formula? I am not sure we should use the interaction or plus.

Comment: Do you expect the effect of a continuous variable to be different for different levels of your categorical predictor? Then you would use an interaction between the terms. Here is a useful explanation of interactions: https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/interaction-effects/
Also, I'm fairly sure a glm with a gaussian family function is just a linear model.

Comment: @spj: A glm with gaussian family function and **an identity link function** is just a linear model.

Comment: There are many similar Qs, please [look through this list](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com+what+is+interaction+in+an+glm%3F&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com+++what+is+interaction+in+an+glm%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.19512j0j4&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thank you, it is so helpful

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen yes, that's right, thank you for pointing it out